Gradual upgrade of an inherited .NET Framework project
I'm seeking advice on the best approach to upgrade a legacy .NET Framework project to a newer version. The project currently consists of over 80 projects, and a complete rewrite would be a time-consuming undertaking.
We're considering a phased approach, where we gradually migrate functionality to newer projects while maintaining the old ones for the time being. This would allow us to benefit from newer features and security improvements without disrupting the existing application.
Our primary question is whether it's feasible to reuse components from the old projects, such as models, methods, and entity contexts, within the new projects. This would save us significant development time and effort.
Would this be the most efficient approach, or is there a more ideal strategy? We're open to suggestions and best practices for tackling this type of migration.
Additional details:

The current project is in .NET Framework 4.5.
We're considering upgrading to .NET 6 or later.
We have a team of experienced developers with expertise in .NET Framework and newer technologies.
We're prioritizing a smooth transition that minimizes disruption to the existing application.

Key considerations:

Technical feasibility: Can we effectively reuse components from the old projects within the new ones?
Development effort: Will reusing existing components save us significant time and effort compared to a complete rewrite?
Long-term maintainability: Will the resulting codebase be maintainable and scalable in the long run?


Have you seen the .NET Migration Documentation?

just change the target framework and see what breaks first. If you have separated out your projects well likely 99% of them will "just work(tm)" Ask a question about the ones that dont.

I see two close votes already. I'm in the midst of precisely this sort of problem, and I do have some advice. Hold the close votes, please!

@GregBurghardt this may be a time to stop worrying and just let the community dissolve in its toxicity :)

@Basilevs, the biggest challenge I've had in life is knowing when it's worth paddling against the rapids versus letting go and floating with the current. I suppose it depends on whether I agree with the direction of the river and how tired my arms are. Apparently my arms aren't that tired today.

"a complete rewrite would be a time-consuming undertaking" Gradual upgrades tend to take more time, not less. However, gradual upgrades can keep the outage time (i.e. time between breaking the old code and finishing the refactored code) to a minimum by spacing out the changes. It is unclear to me whether the key goal here is to minimize the overall hours worked on the refactor (in which case a slow upgrade is the wrong decision) or if you're stuck having to have an always-buildable and continually-evolving codebase that couldn't possibly support a big bang refactor.

Hi @Flater, You're absolutely right about the need for a gradual update that preserves the existing codebase without disrupting its functionality. Time is of the essence, and we can't afford to overhaul the entire system while simultaneously introducing new features. That's why I advocate for incorporating elements of the old into the new.

@Flater, while a rewrite takes less time in absolute terms, .NET 4.8 is still supported by Microsoft, so there is no panic yet. A gradual upgrade allows you to deliver new features in parallel, which is the major win here.

@Flater: gradual updates may tend to take a longer time period in general, but the OP talks about a migration in a context where it is often feasible to make libraries compatible with the old and the new infrastructure at the same time, without reimplementing everything. This is not some "Cobol to Java" migration.

@DocBrown: I don't disagree with you, but the specific quote I responded to (which I included in my comment) implied that OP was choosing to gradually update on the assumption it would take less time. I do agree that gradual updates can make sense regardless of them taking more time.

@GregBurghardt Same comment as above.

@Flater: to be honest, I think this comparison is somewhat dangerous because it gives a wrong impression. Where do we find complex projects where the team really tried both - a gradual migration and a one-step migration, so there is comparable data? The only cases I know where this happened is where teams planned a one-step migration first because they thought it was going quicker. Then this approach failed epicly, and then they switched to a gradual migration afterwards.

@DocBrown The difference between a big bang refactor and one that continually expects the codebase to be buildable (and deployable) is that you need to care about keeping the code buildable and deployable in the latter case. Logically, that can only be extra effort, not less. At the very best, it might be identical effort, but that's idealistic. But it doesn't make logical sense for a continually buildable codebase to require less effort to get to the same destination than a big bang refactor (which will happily leave the codebase broken until they reach their destination) would require.

@DocBrown: The assumption in my above comment is ceteris paribus, i.e. either process eventually delivers the same refactoring. If either process changes the code to something different, you couldn't possibly compare the two.

You will want to target .NET 8, which is the latest version. Using .NET 6 is not recommended because it is out of support (see Microsoft .NET and .NET Core Lifetime Policy).
First, assess the project dependencies to ensure they make sense. I've worked on applications where class libs depended on web projects, and separate web API projects depended on each other. You need to ensure your solution does not have circular dependencies. Visual Studio does a pretty good job of this, but circular dependencies can sneak in if there are enough levels of separation between projects. Don't be afraid to crack open a Visio diagram (or some similar tool) to visually map these dependencies if necessary. If you find indirect circular dependencies between projects, your first order of business is to break these circular dependencies. The rest of the upgrade will go much smoother and allows to selectively upgrading projects, which I believe to be one of your main goals.
The low-hanging fruit for your upgrade will be class libraries that are not directly coupled to the .NET Framework. We use .NET Standard 2.0 for class libraries in one of my projects, because they work with .NET Framework 4.6+ and .NET Core/.NET 5+ projects. Generally speaking, the lower the .NET Standard version number the more .NET runtimes that are compatible. So really, step 1 is to convert class libs to .NET Standard 2.0 and upgrade the other projects to .NET 4.8.x. The upgrade from .NET 4.5 to 4.8 should require minimal effort.
Next step is to upgrade test projects that only rely on those class libs and NuGet packages. These are usually pretty easy and safe to upgrade to the latest version of .NET. The most troubles I've had concerned upgrading NuGet packages, but this is very dependent on the NuGet packages you have installed.
Finally, upgrade projects that are tied to the .NET framework. These are things like web and web API projects, Windows services and console applications. This is where project dependencies begin to matter.
Roughly, these are the steps to take:

Break indirect circular dependencies between projects.
Upgrade projects to .NET 4.8 which still receives security fixes and supports .NET Standard 2.0.
Upgrade class libs to .NET Standard 2.0, which works on .NET 4 and .NET Core/.NET 5+.

This will include hunting down newer versions of 3rd party NuGet packages which are compatible with .NET 4.8 and .NET Standard.
I've run into a slight snag using FluentValidation. It looks like the v8 series of FluentValidation is the last one that had good integration with .NET Framework 4 ASP.NET MVC applications. You can upgrade to the latest version of FluentValidation for those projects, but you lose client-side validations. Properly done, this is an inconvenience for the end user and should be resolved once you upgrade to .NET 8.


Upgrade test projects for the .NET Standard class libs to the latest .NET version.

And then upgrade any CI/CD pipelines you use as well.


Upgrade the remaining projects which are tightly coupled to .NET 4.

Again, CI/CD pipelines will likely be impacted by this.



Some other considerations:

With 80 projects in one solution, dependencies might be difficult to untangle. Analyze which ones are cohesive, and consider upgrading the whole group of projects at once.
Automated tests are you friends. If you don't have good test coverage, consider writing tests first before attempting to upgrade. They can be unit tests, integration tests, or end-to-end tests. The important thing is that you have tests.

Planning For The Future
Once you've done the big lift-and-shift into the new framework, you can retarget the .NET Standard libraries to .NET 8, however .NET Standard will continue being supported moving forward. Changing from .NET Standard to .NET 8 should only be necessary if your application needs to utilize APIs that are not available in .NET Standard.
Limitations Of This Approach
I have not needed to deal with C++ projects yet. The available .NET framework APIs and any third party libraries will be the major hurdles with upgrading C++ projects. I don't have a lot of advice here due to a lack of experience on this front.

Hello, thanks for the information. It helps me have a good idea of where to start. I forgot to mention that I have .ascx views or user controls. When migrating, would I have to convert all of those views to Razor?

@AsdrubalHernandez, check Microsoft's documentation. They might still support those kinds of views, but I don't know offhand. That is another consideration.

I plan on updating my answer. I saw two close-votes, so I was racing the community to answer before it got closed.

doesnt net 8 replace net standard?

.NET Standard is just that: a standard of the C# language API and .NET 8 is an implementation of that standard --- .NET Standard is to HTML 5 as .NET 8 is to Google Chrome v126, as an illustration.

Hi Everyone, I have been searching for a lot of information to migrate the version, but almost all the posts or information I find is based on version 4.5.1. I currently have 4.5 and I see that the way to migrate changes many things relative to that version. Any post where I can see information about that specific version?

@AsdrubalHernandez It should not change anything at all when it comes to upgrading/migrating to .NET 8; Changes between .NET 4.x versions are trivial and not worth wasting time which would be better spent on getting to the very real problems with dependencies that Greg mentioned.  In every case you always need completely new versions of every tool and dependency you're currently using. That includes the new MSBuild SDK (csproj XML structure), new build tools and compiler, NuGet, all of the .NET libraries and all NuGet packages.   This is where most of the real work is found.

Thanks everyone for the comments. I had a little time this morning to update my answer.
